# I cannot use query def object as a variable in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

NB:UPDATED:::: I want to create a query called comp_val and LEFT JOIN it with a table called FILTERS TABLE. But I cannot use the left join unless I have saved the comp_val SQL string as either a query or a table.
comp_val is a variable that is generated during runtime.
I am trying to create a query definition called que_def and assign a valid sql string to it called "comp_val". Then use the que_def to create a left join query with a table called "FILTERS" table. But access gives me an Type mismatch error saying that I cannot use the que_def as a variable to form the new sql string
here is the code

```
Dim que_def  As QueryDef
Dim all_info As String

Set que_def = db.CreateQueryDef(comp_val) 'new_query is a new sql query whose sql string can be set to comp_val
    que_def.SQL = comp_val 'comp_val is a valid sql string
    
    'after setting the que_def sql value to comp_val, it is supposed to form a new sql string
    p1 = "SELECT " & que_def & ".Company_Name, " & que_def & ".Site_Name, " & que_def & ".Site_Location, " & que_def & ".Site_Contact, Filters_Table.Gen_Combination, " & que_def & ".Capacity(KVA), " & que_def & ".Alt_S/No, " & que_def & ".Engine_S/No, " & que_def & ".Filter_Type, " & que_def & ".Generator_Type,"
    p2 = " Filters_Table.Generator_Name, Filters_Table.Capacity, Filters_Table.Fuel_Filter1_ID, Filters_Table.Fuel_Filter1_Qty, Filters_Table.Fuel_Filter2_ID, Filters_Table.Fuel_Filter2_Qty, Filters_Table.Oil_Filter1_ID, Filters_Table.Oil_Filter1_Qty, Filters_Table.Oil_Filter2_ID, Filters_Table.Oil_Filter2_Qty, Filters_Table.Water_Sep_ID, Filters_Table.Water_Sep_Qty, Filters_Table.Air_Filter_ID, Filters_Table.Air_Filter_Qty, Filters_Table.Engine_Oil1_ID, Filters_Table.Engine_Oil1_Qty, Filters_Table.CF_ID, Filters_Table.CF_Qty"
    p3 = " FROM " & que_def & " LEFT JOIN Filters_Table ON " & que_def & ".Filter_Type = Filters_Table.Gen_Combination;"
    all_info = p1 + p2 + p3
    MsgBox ("IT IS DONE GOING THROUGH IT ALL")
```

But I cannot use the "que_def" variable.I am given the error, type mismatch.

NB: comp_Val is a select query and I am trying to left join it to a table called filter's table and it'supposed to bring a new sql string called all_info.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A querydef is an object, not a string. You need to give it a name to use it in another query.

```
Const qdName = "MyQuery"
Dim que_def  As QueryDef

Set que_def = db.CreateQueryDef(Name:=qdName, SQLText:=comp_val) 

' You did this already when creating the querydef, no need to do it again
' que_def.SQL = comp_val 

'after setting the que_def sql value to comp_val, it is supposed to form a new sql string
p1 = "SELECT " & qdName & ".Company_Name, "
' etc.
```

Comment: hey. I tried your method and there are no errors. However, the code doesn't continue. It just stops, no errors, nothing.
    all_info = p1 & p2 & p3
    MsgBox ("IT IS DONE GOING THROUGH IT ALL")
The message box doesn't get printed. The code actually stops executing even though there are no errors.

Comment: I have also updated the question so you would get what I am going for.

Comment: hey. I have found the answer, 
the problem was that i had added an error handler code to make the system exit if a table doesn't exist. The thing was that it also worked for queries as well. Thank you very very much!!!